# Venturis ADF on Debian - should a system font be provided by texlive-fonts-extra?

Tags: debian, fonts, latex, ttf

I have some previous SVG files that I'm trying to edit with Inkscape that use Venturis ADF. This font is not installed as a "system font" on my current computer, but I understand it should be found there as part of the `texlive-fonts-extra` package. The CTAN mentions that ['OTF or TTF available'](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/allfonts.html); I know LaTeX wants the fonts in a different format - but to be sure, should I be able to register Venturis ADF that comes with TeXLive so it can be used in regular Gnome applications such as Inkscape? If yes, how; if no, where do I find the official TTF sources of Venturis ADF (rather than downloading from a random shady "free fonts" website)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TeX Live packages in Debian only provide the information for TeX and LaTeX, they don’t include the OTF formats. As a result, you can’t use the fonts in `texlive-fonts-extra` with tools such as Inkscape.

However there’s no need to resort to random web sites; you can download the Venturis collection [from the foundry directly](http://arkandis.tuxfamily.org/tugfonts.htm) (look for the WinZip icon alongside “Venturis collection” on the right-hand side; [this is the current download link](http://arkandis.tuxfamily.org/fonts/Venturis-Serie-20100704.zip)).

Comment: Thank you. It took me a moment to realise the 8-bit 1990s "zip icon" is a link to the download :)